# How can I deploy just one file to google app engine?

Tags: go, google-app-engine

I have already deployed my application to google app engine but I have modified just one file and I want to deploy just this file

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible to upload a single file to app engine, every deploy takes the root folder where app.yaml file is located and upload the directories and files.

But if you made some changes or add a single file, the files that are identical are not re-uploaded.

Only the new files or modified are being uploaded, but the new upload creates a [new version of the service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/building-app#services_and_versions).

as stated on the documentation:
"You can update your service at any time by running the `gcloud app deploy command`. Each time you deploy, a new version is created and traffic is automatically routed to the latest version"

Comment: On the other hand, you can also use ".gcloudignore" file to set all files which are not needed to be deployed